# Why would my central bank suddenly increase the interest rates to over 20%?

Tags: economy, alternate-history, united-states

**Question**: My plotline is an alternate history of the US and requires the Federal Reserve bank to increase the prime interest rate to an unheard-of 20% for one full year.

The political environment is identical to ours until this event. Some statistics about the Federal Reserve Bank are included below to help understand historical responses:

- The Federal Reserve Act created the Federal Reserve  on December 23 1913.
- The annualized US inflation rate was [7.5% in January 2022, "the highest since February of 1982".](https://tradingeconomics.com/united-states/inflation-cpi). (I am mulling the possibility in the question Title).
- The global maximum Federal Funds Rate was [17.6% in April 1980](https://www.jacobinmag.com/2019/12/paul-adolph-volcker-obituary-federal-reserve-chair), during Paul Volcker's tenure.
- [Since 1775, US inflation outstripped 20% merely twice. It outreached 15% from 1916-20.](https://www.wsj.com/articles/a-brief-history-of-u-s-inflation-since-1775-1450115182?tesla=y.)

[image: https://images.jacobinmag.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/09165248/Volcker-years-900x640.png]

- Recessions have had [a profound impact on the prime interest rate](https://theweek.com/articles/618964/forgotten-recession-that-irrevocably-damaged-american-economy).
- Certain individuals - specifically the 'Fed' - [can make decisions](http://www.socialisteconomist.com/2020/01/rip-paul-adolph-volcker.html) that cause their own bank to respond dramatically.
- [Comparing several Feds](https://econfix.wordpress.com/2013/10/21/interest-rates-under-volcker-greenspan-and-bernanke/) can be helpful in determining the socio-economic causes of a high-interest rate response.

As the tags indicate, this is not asking to invent anything fantastical or supernatural. The story needs an extended 20% prime rate to work, I am hoping for a believable cause for it.

Comment: What is the worldbuilding context?  As worded, this sounds like an attempt to get some strangers to do your economics homework for you.

Comment: @KerrAvon2055 no. this is absolutely NOT economics homework. I am exploring this possibility in a short fiction story.

Comment: There are extreme recession scenarios to find on WB. This reminds me of an earlier SAP-500 question https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/218738/barring-asteroid-impacts-disease-natural-disaster-war-why-would-the-sp-500

Comment: Please edit your query to include the worldbuilding context. Comments can be moved to chat and it is preferable to edit questions to include all relevant information.

Comment: As it stands, your query is closed. Not because it's unsuitable or off topic, but simply because you have not given any fictional context. I have no idea what you're talking about, so won't answer the question, but even I can see that information like "who's the president", "what is the current political climate", "who's on the Court and who holds Congress", "what's going on in the country" and "what's going on in the world are all things you need to specify. Since you're writing a fictional story, you probably have all that stuff worked out -- please fill us in so you can get good answers!

Comment: (cont) -- Get this edited to add some context and I'll be happy to vote to reopen!

Comment: I've put some edits, mainly order of things, and an explicit question, making it clear this is a fictional scenario and not economics homework.

Comment: This type of "taxation" has happened in history - when a country was conquered and had to pay "reparations" or tribute. Similar things have happened when a bank was taken over and all the borrowers were told to either repay the loans now or pay a huge interest rate.

Comment: Well Russia did just that this February so that's a good example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Something quick and big

Note: this 20% is excessive... *supposed* inflation is not. In Venezuela, a  20% rate would be a recovery.

https://www.statista.com/statistics/454492/interest-rates-on-fixed-1-year-deposits-by-country/

**Asteroid?**

Interest rate is actually the price of money. That price explodes. The fed hopes people will take a sprint to the bank and put all their money in a savings account asap to get this 20%, instead of consuming and investing their money. It would cause a rapid decline of consumption and investments, and a wave of money flowing into the Fed, and the banks.

The explanation could be, that some trusted entity needs tons of money, for some very important purpose. Say, the government and NASA  had to lend this money, trillions, to quickly build 100s of  spaceships with nukes, to blow up an incoming asteroid.

**Pandemia?**

Decline in consumption, stocks plunge, economy cooling down..

We've had Covid, in recent years.. 1%-4% death rate, and spreading in weeks. Now suppose you'd have a virus as deadly as Ebola, with a 20% death rate, and spreading even faster. In that case, you'd need an *immediate* lockdown measure, freeze the economy and invest trillions in measures and vaccine distribution. An increase in savings interest rate at banks could give people confidence they can "sit it out" at home.. and provide the money to the government, for the necessary support/relief policies and logistics.

Comment: *"The government and NASA had to lend this money, trillions, to quickly build <stuff>":* (1) NASA has no money to lend. NASA is fed from the (American) national budget. (2) The government can lend as much money as they want. They have no need to collect it first from depositors -- all they need to do is ask nicely Mr. Jerome Powell, Chair of the Board of Governors of the Federal Reserve System, to write *this piece of paper is worth ecks bazillion dollars* on a piece of paper and kindly sign his name. Done.

Comment: 1) I consider Nasa and the government as one, I only named them to indicate the target 2) I'm not going to get involved in political discussions, but the government chose not to do that, they wanted to avoid a public vote on incoming asteroids. Above scenario can be prepared in secret, 1-2 between the Fed and the government, the Fed will poroduce a technical reason no one understands and it becomes manifest when the project has started, not months earlier.

Answer (score 5):

## Ideology:

I like the answer @Goodies, gave, but I don't think the government would react that way even to a massive disaster. If the government did this, I don't think it would be due to logic. I think it would be due to ideology.

I remember as a college student discussing the insertion of broad government powers in response to a crisis, and "well, maybe if there was a huge global pandemic" was the exception that even extreme conservatives cited at the time. But we can see that even in the case of a huge global pandemic, ideology wins out, and people will act irrationally in a variety of complex ways.

So if a president with a 'quirky' idea of US financial policy was elected and put in extremist-ideologs who believed that a 25% increase was what we needed to get the economy back on a "rational" path, then they could ride out the economic disruptions, possibly up to 4 years, as they all insist it's for the best despite the consequences.

Implausible? I would argue that the whole Soviet economy was built on similar ideological optimism despite evidence to the contrary. I also remember when I was younger wishing that I could get politicians who at least believed in something genuine and weren't cynically political. Now I wish for politicians willing to compromise their personal ethics to keep the government running. So you just need a handful of influential people to take control of the government and to believe in a crackpot economic theory founded on an extremely high federal reserve rate.

Comment: Well @DWKraus if an asteroid comes flying in, or you have a worldwide health disaster at hand, some ideology (*enhancing* social coherence instead of undermining it) could help a *government*, to contain the panic.. but I'm afraid ideology won't kick in. You are right, it kicks in on the other side. In my scenario, that is of later concern. The powers   that be (Fed etc) choose the most obvious route, market-wise, that is: raise rates, to get the money in quickly.. and start the work to save the world. Don't forget both my scenario's are worldwide disasters, everyone knows what is going on.

Comment: @Goodies Don't get me wrong, if you're looking for a logical reason, yours is good. I'm guessing they'd just print money or impose marital law instead. Since all growth in consumption for a global disaster is directed, it wouldn't affect inflation (I don't think). The hatred of interest rate hikes in the US is too semi-religious to be a useful tool.

Comment: Inflation follows in due time.. The move itself is a matter of urgency. When a large bank would be in danger in a European country, you could see  a similar reflex. There are many more reasons, to increase interest rates. But +20% in the US is a bizarre scenario to think of.. and fictional. Regret the closure, this kind of "what happened" hypothetical questions are poorly understood on WB.